# How to add more Browse by sidebar blocks

Tags: product, category, search

At the moment in my 2 column website design, in my left sidebar i have the standard browse by category when there are sub categories, then once you have clicked on the sub category, i have nothing in my sidebar.

What i would like to do is add another browse by or sort by block for things like brand, price, length etc.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

I have added these properties as attributes.

I have looked around on the web but cant find much information, whether that's because there isn't or im not terming it correctly im not sure.

If you want more explanation please ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to display the layered navigation (I'm assuming thats what you are talking about) you need to set the `is anchor` attribute to `yes` in the categories which need to have layered navigation.

You've already mentioned you set several attributes to `use in layered navigation` so after refreshing your cache the layered navigation block should show up on the category pages in the frontend.

[image: Set is achor to yes]

Comment: i went to do what you suggested and i got this error for some reason "Default Product Listing Sort by not exists on Available Product Listing Sort By" Any Ideas

Comment: Ah i see what this does now, this just adds the option to sort the products by an attribute from the drop down menu, what i meant was to get something (a block?) in the left side column that the user can select price ranges they want or select brands they like, does this make more sense? thanks

Comment: `Default product sorting` is a category option. Perhaps the products in this category do not have that attribute? Not too sure about it. Check https://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673949/available-product-listing-sort-by-will-not-remove-options-from-drop-down they seem relevant

Comment: Ok i got it working using the leyered naivgation and attributes, but this seems to only work with the first level of sub categories and none under them?

Comment: Sorted had to use is anchor!

Comment: You must either set `Is anchor` or `Use Parent Category Settings` (if parent is anchor) to yes on all sub categories for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok SO to answer my own question i had to make sure the attribute was using layered navigation, and then add these attributes i created into an attribute set. I then proceeded to re-create all of my products using this new attribute set.

As an extra note, i realised that the sort only showed in the left column on the first level of sub navs and none below it. It was because when i created my categories i didn't have "Is Anchor" set to yes. So if you have the same problem simply set it as yes.

Now to find out how to set different attribute sets for different categories! ha

Thanks for the help Sander!